# Sage pay Unable to redirect to vendor's website

Tags: c#, e-commerce, opayo

I have followed all the answers related to this question, but still I am getting `Unable to redirect to vendor's website` error.

I have opened `PORT 443,80` and have also `whitelisted` the IP address of Sage pay.

Somewhere I read that the Notification URL we pass is a bit confusing, it is not a URL but a Handler. This is my URL

```
string NotificationURL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxxx/Confirm.aspx";
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong or missing

**EDITED**

Below is my log file, everything in the log file seems to be correct. The server is hitting the Confirm.aspx page I passed as NotificationURL

```
2016-07-30 19:41:05 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /services/data.ashx method=bookTable 80 - 150.107.91.31 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 http://tcb.gtg.tech/home.html tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 3420
2016-07-30 19:41:51 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /services/data.ashx method=paydeposit 80 - 150.107.91.31 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 http://tcb.gtg.tech/home.html tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 1640
2016-07-30 19:42:16 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /Confirm.aspx/ - 80 - 195.170.169.29 HTTP/1.1 SagePay-Notifier/1.0 - tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 328
2016-07-30 19:42:16 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /Confirm.aspx/ - 80 - 195.170.169.29 HTTP/1.1 SagePay-Notifier/1.0 - tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 156
2016-07-30 19:42:16 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /Confirm.aspx/ - 80 - 195.170.169.29 HTTP/1.1 SagePay-Notifier/1.0 - tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 156
2016-07-30 19:42:16 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /Confirm.aspx/ - 80 - 195.170.169.29 HTTP/1.1 SagePay-Notifier/1.0 - tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 140
2016-07-30 19:42:16 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /Confirm.aspx/ - 80 - 195.170.169.29 HTTP/1.1 SagePay-Notifier/1.0 - tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 156
2016-07-30 19:42:16 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /Confirm.aspx/ - 80 - 195.170.169.29 HTTP/1.1 SagePay-Notifier/1.0 - tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 140
2016-07-30 19:42:16 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /Confirm.aspx/ - 80 - 195.170.169.29 HTTP/1.1 SagePay-Notifier/1.0 - tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 156
2016-07-30 19:42:18 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /Confirm.aspx/ - 80 - 195.170.169.29 HTTP/1.1 SagePay-Notifier/1.0 - tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 140
2016-07-30 19:42:18 W3SVC18 UBAIDMOHAMMADVM xx.xx.xx.xxx POST /Confirm.aspx/ - 80 - 195.170.169.29 HTTP/1.1 SagePay-Notifier/1.0 - tcb.gtg.tech 200 0 0 140
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 5006 error that is being returned? Are you receiving a notification response from Sage Pay via your Notification URL?

The following is a list of steps that can be used to troubleshoot a 5006 error:

1. Make sure the Notification URL is externally accessible
2. You must acknowledge receipt of the transaction response with a Status of either OK, INVALID or ERROR,
3. Clear the response buffer to remove any header code, comments or HTML. The Sage Pay Server is expecting “Status=” to be the first characters in the response.
4. The NotificationURL should ONLY respond with a Status field, a RedirectURL field and optionally a StatusDetail field.
   4.The RedirectURL must be valid. Regardless of status, the RedirectURL must be sent that contains a valid, Fully Qualified URL (i.e. an address starting http:// or https://).
5. Encoding in the response must be as Name=Value fields separated by carriage-return-linefeeds (CRLF).
6. The NotificationURL should be able to handle correctly all the messages sent by Sage Pay (OK, ABORT, NOTAUTHED, REJECTED, PENDING and ERROR).
7. A status of OK should be sent in all circumstances where no errors occur in validating the Notification POST. Even if a status of ABORT or NOTAUTHED is received, a reply with an OK and a RedirectURL is expected.
8. Ensure that all of the following IP addresses are allowed within the Server or Firewall:

For outbound traffic:
195.170.169.9 – live.sagepay.com
195.170.169.8 – test.sagepay.com

The IPs from which Sage Pay call back are:

195.170.169.14

195.170.169.18

195.170.169.15

Comment: Just to clarify, regarding "Clear the response buffer to remove any header code" - we left the headers in and it worked fine.